# Cannot reset mock count call on Jest

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I have a test:

```js
import csvDownload from "../../../utils/methods/csvDownload";

jest.mock("../../../utils/methods/csvDownload");

describe("Test Dashboard Page", () => {
  it("Test can dowload csv", async () => {
    csvDownload.mockResolvedValue(null);
    renderWithProviders(<DashboardPage />);
    await waitFor(() => {
      const downloadCsv = screen.getByText("97");
      fireEvent.click(downloadCsv);
      expect(csvDownload).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

But I have a bigger amount of times called (~ 70).

Cannot reset that count.

I have seen this question: [How to reset Jest mock functions calls count before every test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47812801/how-to-reset-jest-mock-functions-calls-count-before-every-test)

so adding the afterEach:

```js
import csvDownload from "../../../utils/methods/csvDownload";

jest.mock("../../../utils/methods/csvDownload");

afterEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});

describe("Test Dashboard Page", () => {
  it("Test can dowload csv", async () => {
    csvDownload.mockResolvedValue(null);
    renderWithProviders(<DashboardPage />);
    await waitFor(() => {
      const downloadCsv = screen.getByText("97");
      fireEvent.click(downloadCsv);
      expect(csvDownload).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

(Tried also `csvDownload.resetMock()` without luck)

Comment: There's a chance you may be putting a little too much work into the "waitFor" function. What is the mock value you're seeing when you run "Test can download csv"?

Comment: At the end I solved moving the method under test in another file and making a ligh refactor of code. For real, when a method makes too many things, it is difficult to test it.